# vs code open same files at home like in office

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

Is it possible to sync the list of open files, so that at my home computer in VS Code the same files are opened automatically? I know I can synchronize settings etc. but unfortunately the open files are not synchronized.

My developer environment

- Computer at the office (macOS)
- Other computer at home (macOS)
- Development server Raspberry Pi 4

That means with this setup I use VS Code to remotely change the files on the Raspberry Pi. Now I want VS Code at home to automatically have the same files open as the computer at the office has.

Automatically syncing the open files would help me a lot.